Если писать о герое произведения «Премудрый пискарь», то имя его (премудрый пискарь) пишем с заглавной?
Премудрый Пискарь всю свою жизнь прожил в постоянном страхе. Он боялся всего...

Думаю, можно закавычить, а писать как в оригинале с маленькой буквы оба слова - "премудрый пискарь". Если же название произведения, то с заглавной буквы.
Причём, что интересно, С.-Щедрин написал "пИскарь", а не пескарь.

Пискарь, ошибочно см. пескарь, от песок, хотя его и зовут на Уроле
пискан, а твер. пск. пискушек. Даль.

Вроде как пескарь производная от писк, потому что пойманная рыбка пищит. Возможно, С.-Щедрин так же обыгрывал момент с "писклявым мудрецом" в названии.
Также похожее мнение нашёл, выражающее ещё одну версию происхождения слова:

первоначально название рыбы - калька с латинского piscus, так что
правильно было писать пИскарь, а вот позже название этой рыбы стало
ассоциироваться с песком, и писать стали пЕскарь. сейчас пескарь -
норма. что качается сочинения, можно писать пИскарь в кавычках как
цитату С-Щ, в остальных случаях лучше пользоваться нормой.


Я тоже думаю, что кавычки в тексте вполне возможны: "премудрый пискарь". Это как бы ЦИТИРОВАНИЕ автора и одновременно ирония, ведь окружающие не ситали его премудрым, даже наоборот.  Кроме того, в рассказе только одно имя собственное - это название рассказа. А пескарь имени не имеет, это нарицательное существительное с авторским художественным определением.  Он использует его в тексте пару раз как определение, а не имя персонажа. Поэтому лучше  по возможности реже употреблять это сочетание или не использовать совсем, что все и делают.  Можно назвать его очень умным и т .д.

Если у автора оба слова со строчной, то нет оснований писать по-другом. Он мог бы называть героя чрезмерно умной рыбой. Это ж не имя. Собственно, имя в этой истории не нужно, потому что это абстракция, притча, универсальный образ.
